# Missing image in rails using paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I am very new to rails and attempting to build my first project.
I have a problem whilst adding images using paperclip.
Basically whenever I attempt to upload an image to a post, it still keeps the "missing" image.Any help is greatly appreciated.
Here is my model

```
 class Pt < ActiveRecord::Base
        validates :name, presence: true
        has_attached_file :image, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100#" }
        validates_attachment_content_type :image, :content_type => ["image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/png", "image/gif"]
    end


  and my controller

class PersonaltrainersController < ApplicationController
  def index
      @PT = Pt.all
  end

  def new
      @PT = Pt.new
  end

  def show
      @PT = Pt.find(params[:id])
  end
def destroy
    @PT = Pt.find(params[:id])
  @PT.destroy

  redirect_to personaltrainers_path
end
def edit
      @PT = Pt.find(params[:id])
  end

    def update
        @PT = Pt.find(params[:id])
  if @PT.update(params[:pt].permit(:name, :age, :sex, :experience))
      redirect_to personaltrainer_path
        flash[:notice] = "The trainer was updated."
        else
            flash[:error] = "Something went wrong."
            render :edit
        end
            end

  def create
    @PT = Pt.new(params[:pt].permit(:name, :age, :sex, :experience))
      if @PT.save
            flash[:success] = "Successfully added a post."
            redirect_to personaltrainers_path
       else 
            flash[:error] = "Please check the form for errors and try again."
            render :new
        end
 end
      end
  def contact
  end
```

and my show page

```
<h1> <%= @PT.name %></h1>
<h2> <%= @PT.age %></h2>
<body>
<%= @PT.experience %>
</body>
<br>
<%= image_tag @PT.image.url()%>
<%= link_to "edit", edit_personaltrainer_path %>
<%= link_to "delete", personaltrainer_path, method: :delete, confirm: true %>
```

Comment: Please show us a your current form for `@PT` where you tried to adding image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with your permit params, this part:

```
params[:pt].permit(:name, :age, :sex, :experience)
```

Should include the `:image` attribute of your `Pt` model. So, you need this as your permit params:

```
params[:pt].permit(:name, :age, :sex, :experience, :image)
```

That should allow your image to be saved correctly. Remember to check your server logs often, they will show warnings such as "Unpermitted parameters: :image" when you forget to add an attribute to your permit params.